# Microsoft says 2TB limit is the for azure VM OS Disk, What exactly it means?

Tags: azure

I came across a scenario where I need to create an Azure VM with the OS disk(contains OS and data) more than 2TB space. But I saw this warning in the Microsoft portal saying OS disk limit is 2TB.

[image]

I am aware that we can increase disk size more than 2TB but I am confused with this statement as it's not explaining in detail the problems if we go beyond 2TB.

I am choosing Linux OS and want to install application software and store the data used by that software in the disk. In the future, that data might grow beyond 2TB. If it happens, What challenges will I see because of this 2TB limitation?

Does anyone have a clear idea of what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that warning? It looks quite different to me:

[image]

I don't think this is meant to be a hard limit by Azure, just a suggestion that your OS might not be able to handle a system disk greater than 2 TB in size; I'd suggest to just try and see if it works.

But anyway, why do you need such a big system disk? That's really bad practice; you said you are using Linux, thus you should be able to use a data disk and mount it to the path where you want your data stored, in a way completely transparent to any application using it.

Comment: It is a hard limit - but not by Azure. Some (older mostly) operating systems ahve a hard limit that they can not address more than 2tb discs. This was also a problem when hard discs went over this limit - but it was removed quite fast for most operating systems back in the day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can’t really say if it’s not supported but might work or it’s an actual limit but the same limit is documented in the docs pages for OS disk (managed disk).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview#os-disk

> Every virtual machine has one attached operating system disk. That OS disk has a pre-installed OS, which was selected when the VM was created. This disk contains the boot volume.
> This disk has a maximum capacity of 2,048 GiB.